# Michelson Application Binary Interface

Tags: michelson

Is there an Application Binary Interface for Michelson contracts (akin to Ethereum ABI)?

Answer (score 1):

Michelson is a higher level language than the EVM so, typically, contract parameters are expressed in human understandable types (integer, date, amount of tez) with understandable names (using annotations) and not as a binary blob.

Comment: Suppose one wants to define several functions/methods in a contract, wouldn't it make sense to have some conventions, at least for dispatching?

Comment: Yes, an emerging one is to use

Comment: nested "or" for different entry points, with annotations for the name of the entry point. See for instance the input types produced by Liquidity.